# How to set border to every Gridview Image item dynamically

Tags: android, gridview, border

I want to Show different border of every gridview item. how can i set border to every item dynamically .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
    android:layout_width="30px"
    android:layout_height="30px"
    android:src="@drawable/shape" >
</ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main layout file :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:numColumns="15" 
    android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:background="#f3f3f3"
    >
</GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main Class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(
               getApplicationContext(),
               /*((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label)).getText() + */String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
            imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);


        }
    });
```

Adapter Class:

```
 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;

public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        gridView = new View(context);
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mobile, null);
    } else {
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }

    return gridView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 300;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
```

}

**EDIT**

i have added a shape file to my custom design file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@null" />
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
<padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
android:bottom="1dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263611/border-for-an-image-view-in-android

Comment: by using this this will set same boarder to every image, can i set this dynamically where image is binding, i will made array of colors and then i will set at there border.

Comment: try it out i have not done that. give your idea try

Answer (score 2):

Save a `XML` file in your `Drawable` folder with this code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_enabled="true"><shape>
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#CACACA" />

            <corners android:radius="5dp" />

     <!--       <padding android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp" />-->
        </shape></item>

</selector>
```

Now use this as a `background` of your `image view` and set your iamges as `background resources`

Comment: i want to change the color of border not the background

Answer (score 1):

Inside your class ImageAdapter --> getView(...) method, add this line before  `return gridView;` statement

```
gridView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

**Edit**

Also add `android:layout_margin="10dp"` in your image view...

Take [this for ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12047760/2345913).. In the provided link border is applied to complete grid view , but its gives an idea of border setting, use my logic mentioned to achieve this..

Hope this helps..

Comment: this has set my image's bg color , but i want to set border

Comment: i want to set Border color not background color

Comment: You must set background and also set `android:layout_margin="10dp"` for imageView, it will look like a border

Comment: R u kidding sir.... i want to set Border dynamically to every image... i have already set a simple border, but i need to change it in java file, i will make a array of colors and set acording to its position

Comment: and i have searched many things but don't find answer that's y i have posted question

Comment: Well, if you have an array of colors then even better,, setcolors depending on position..like `if(position == 0){gridView.setBackgroundColor(Color[position]);}else{....}`

Comment: why you again come on BackgroundColor , i want to change only border color , not the background color, background color will transparent in every image

Answer (score 1):

```
gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.iMyGridview);
gridView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
gridView.setVerticalSpacing(1);
gridView.setHorizontalSpacing(1);
```