# Show GridView Items in a Frame

Tags: android, xml, gridview, drawable, xml-drawable

How to `show` grid view `item` in a `frame`, I am using **GridView** in my application and now i have to show each and every `grid item` within a `frame`

I am using `black` color as `background`, and want to use `frame` of some `other color` (like:white), so how can i use `white` as frame of griditems

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        />
```

Comment: `setImageBackground` for Frame and `setImageResource` for your Image else you can use masking Effect.

Comment: @SilentKiller why i am not getting setImageBackground option, i am using already using setImageResource like this: viewHolder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

Comment: you can do it with `imageView.setBackgroundDrawable();`

Comment: @SilentKiller i tried this: android:background="@color/white" showing when image has not downloaded, but not getting white in corner of grid images - resolution (W-320xH-180)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For showing image in frame there are two ways to do so

1. Set Background Image or Color to show image is in Frame
2. Set Masking

**For setting BackGround :**

```
<ImageView
    android:id = "@+id/imageItem"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds = "true"
    android:scaleType = "center"
    android:padding = "5dp"
    android:background = "#FFFFFF"
    android:contentDescription = "@null" />
```

**For Masking check following code :**

```
ImageView mImageView= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview_id);
Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.content_image);
Bitmap mask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.mask);
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(mask.getWidth(), mask.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(result);
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
mCanvas.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, null);
mCanvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, paint);
paint.setXfermode(null);
mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
mImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_frame);
```

- [For More Details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12637039/1160282)
- [Source Code](https://github.com/hotveryspicy/MaskImage)

If you want to show color as background then first option will be much better and efficient too.

Comment: thank you so much, such an easy and best way, use padding...may i know what to use if i want to show red color in place of white when user tap on grid item ?

Comment: you just need to change backGround color of ImageView from `#FFFFFF` to `#FF0000` its a combination of RGB #RRGGBB.

Comment: no i am asking how to change frame color when user do tap on griditem ?

Comment: @Sophie i am saying same thing as currently White color is the frame color so you just need to change Color to Red.

Answer (score 0):

Save a `XML` file in your `Drawable` folder with this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_enabled="true"><shape>
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#CACACA" />

        <corners android:radius="5dp" />

 <!--       <padding android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp" />-->
    </shape></item>
```

Now use this as a background of your image view and set your images as background resources.
[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17101948/1545584)

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@drawable/your_xml_name"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        />
```