# GridLayout separator lines

Tags: java, android

I am using a 3x3 GridLayout as shown in the following code:

```
    <GridLayout
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="true"
    android:rowOrderPreserved="true"
    android:layout_width="400sp"
    android:layout_height="400sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/glayout">

    // I am using here 9 buttons

</GridLayout>
```

I was wondering if there is any way to set a color for the separator lines between rows and columns.

Comment: You should have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047369/how-to-set-border-of-gridview-on-android)

Comment: Try ths https://stackoverflow.com/a/23891978/7505436