# Android gridview divider drawable between images

Tags: android, gridview, divider

I have a gridview of images, i need to add one drawable image as a separator between images in gridview.

anyone help me how to add.?

Answer (score -1):

try this hope help

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

    <!-- Cell contents -->

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_selected="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_border_selected" 
    />
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_border_selected" 
    />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_border" 
    />
</selector>
```

**item_border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid 
        android:color="@android:color/transparent" 
    />
    <stroke 
        android:width="1px" 
        android:color="@color/list_divider" 
    />
</shape>
```

**item_border_selected.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid 
        android:color="@color/list_select" 
    />
    <stroke 
        android:width="1px" 
        android:color="@color/list_divider" 
    />
</shape>
```

**items_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-1px"
    android:layout_marginRight="-1px"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
/>
```

Since all lines double in size as they join their neighboring cells, I made the divider size 1px instead of 1dp so it doesn't appear too large on some screens. Also, I made the grid view have negative margins to hide the lines on either side. I hope this helps someone.from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132030/android-gridview-draw-dividers/7304166#7304166)

Comment: I have an image in the drawable folder deepak, i need to add this image as separator between gridview images by setting image width and height to 2dp and 128dp.think your answer is not suitable for my requirement

Comment: See a similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7304166/435605. Both answers are quite similar with a year difference. I wander if it was copied without giving a credit...

Comment: @kilaka hey friend you can see a word from here in end of my answer and also that i have not updated my answer. ok answers are similar but i have already gave credit to original answer.. please check first after comment..